# SVC WebService works over HTTP, fails over HTTPS

Tags: ajax, web-services, https

One of my colleagues is having a problem with an AJAX call to a .NET WebService.  The call works under HTTP, but the same call is having a problem under HTTPS.  The webservice is written in .NET 4.0 with C# on an IIS 7 server.

The secure website is at https://sql.data-rx.com/grouppharmdrugsearch/.  There is an unsecured version at http://sql.data-rx.com/grouppharmdrugsearch/.  There isn't any sensitive information on the page itself.  It is embedded (I believe in a frame) on a client's website that does use HTTPS, and our page needs to be in HTTPS so browsers don't give a mixed secured/unsecured elements present message.

To test the problem on the site you first have to enter a zip code in the second textbox (I have been using 90210 for testing) and then you can enter the first few letters of a drug into the third textbox.  After waiting a second or so for additional letters the page calls the webservice to populate a drop down list of possible drug choices beginning with the supplied letters.  The secure webservice call is to https://sql.data-rx.com/grouppharmdrugsearch/Service/drugNameAutocomplete.svc/GetDrugList with POST data for 'prefixText' and 'count'.  Under HTTP the service call succeeds and populates the drop down;  under HTTPS the call gets a 404 error.  The HTTPS web service is reachable if you point a browser to https://sql.data-rx.com/grouppharmdrugsearch/Service/drugNameAutocomplete.svc, but the method isn't recognized when it is appended to the service.

I have been using Firefox's Tamper Data addon to compare the service calls and they appear to be exactly the same, except one is to the HTTPS site and one is to the HTTP site, with the referrers changing appropriately.  The HTTPS call receives the 404 error, while the HTTP call receives the JSON data.

I believe there may either be something missing from the webservice that would allow the call to function under HTTPS (though I can't think of anything that should matter in this case), or the HTTPS web site itself was misconfigured when it was setup.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We finally figured out the solution from [this site](http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2008/02/20/wcf-bindings-needed-for-https.aspx).  Basically the binding was only configured for HTTP, not HTTPS, and we need to create a custom binding to allow the webservice to function over HTTPS.

Comment: its work fine! just add binding block and set property. TNX man ;)