# Web SVC works on HTTP but not HTTPS

Tags: web-services, wcf, https

I've tried several solutions posted around the net, but none of them appear to work.

The response I get to the web service method is:

> 404: File or directory not found.

When I visit the http version of the *AddressService.svc* file, I get a service description. When I visit the method (*AddressService.svc/ValidateAddress*) I get "GET method not allowed", which is expected because it's a POST method only. When I try the **https** version of the *AddressService.svc* page I also get the service description. However, when I try to visit the method (*AddressService.svc/ValidateAddress*), I get the 404/not found result.

Here is what I've got in my web.config currently:

Binding:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WebServiceSoap">
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Service:

```
  <service name="DefiningVoiceWeb.AddressService" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="DefiningVoiceWeb.IAddressService" behaviorConfiguration="web" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="https://www.definingvoice.com/AdminOnly/AddressService.svc" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
```

Service Behavior:

```
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
```

And I've also added this for CORS:

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <add name="X-Powered-By" value="ASP.NET" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Here's my IAddressService declaration:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAddressService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = "/ValidateAddress",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Address ValidateAddress(Address address);
}
```

And the AddressService.svc:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="DefiningVoiceWeb.AddressService" CodeBehind="AddressService.svc.cs" %>
```

I've tried solutions from these pages, but none of them appear to work for me:

- [How to convert wcf http web service to https](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F22382057%2Fhow-to-convert-wcf-http-web-service-to-https&ei=pONeVOnMMZD5yQS4voCYDQ&usg=AFQjCNEQwY5j-V45K8O6Cy176fAlmOn7BA&sig2=4r2_V1kx_rv3jLdf01sUZQ&bvm=bv.79189006,d.aWw)
- [SVC WebService works over HTTP, fails over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248035/svc-webservice-works-over-http-fails-over-https)
- [WCF Bindings Needed For HTTPS](http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/wcf-bindings-needed-for-https)

I'm happy to try one of the solutions above if it's possible I did something wrong.  Let me know if I need to supply more details.

Thanks in advance.

---

After reading through the link provided by @pepo I found the problem. Here are the sections I edited with the final working configuration:

Service:

```
  <service name="DefiningVoiceWeb.AddressService" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpTransportSecurity" contract="DefiningVoiceWeb.IAddressService" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="https://www.definingvoice.com/AdminOnly/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
```

Binding:

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpTransportSecurity">
      <security mode="Transport">
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: Have you looked in the eventlog? What happens when you access the service metadata from localhost? There should be more information about what is missing to activate the service.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the event log where I'm hosting the site. I'll try running the site under https in IIS Express on my localhost. I hadn't thought to try that. I'll try that now...

Comment: Ok, I made some progress. After running on localhost I found some issues with the web.config. I reverted to the working config from the http configuration then added some decoration like the mode="Transport" and others from the examples above. Now I get a description of the service when I go to https//...AddressService.svc which is similar to the http version, but when I try to access the method AddressService.svc/ValidateAddress the responses are different (see updates above). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, why do you edit `basicHttp` binding configuration when you are using weHttpBinding?

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096480/how-to-secure-webhttpbinding) might help you (I didn't test it though). There is a nice article referenced explaining how to set up https with webHttpBinding.

Comment: That's a good article. Thanks for the link. I'll read through it tonight and try to match my solution to his example.

Comment: Finally! The problem, at least I think, was that I was using basicHttpBinding instead of webHttpBinding and I wasn't adding the bindingConfiguration to the service. I'll post my revisions. Thanks  again for the link. It was a good article.